# R: Girar etiquetas del eje x en un barplot

Tags: r, rstudio

Quería saber la forma de inclinar **(determinados grados a la derecha)** las etiquetas del eje `x` de un `barplot`.
Cuando corro el `script` del `barplot`:

```
     barplot(Indexpercentage, horiz = FALSE, col = c("Green","Orange","Red","Blue"), beside = FALSE, xlim=c(0,5),ylab ="Diversity (%)", xlab="Diversity measure",font.axis=2, cex.axis = 0.8,cex.names = 0.8,font.lab=2,yaxp = c(0, 100,4))
```

Obtengo este `plot`, del que no se puede leer las etiquetas de la segunda y cuarta columna (supongo que porque se solaparan)

[image: Barplot]

Además me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de que aparezca la linea del eje `x` abajo del `barplot`.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el problema de las etiquetas del eje X tiene que ver con el solapamiento, puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. Agrandar el gráfico: Simplemente ampliando la ventana de plot de Rstudio,o haciendo click en el botón de zoom.
2. Mostrar las etiquetas en forma vertical mediante el parámetro `las=2` junto con la función `axis()`

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
colnames(counts) <- c("Etiqueta 1", "Etiqueta 2", "Etiqueta 3")
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una forma es usando el parámetro `las=2` de la siguiente forma:

```
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts), las=2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si además quieres un eje X, puedes usar `axis()`:

```
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts),
        names.arg = c(NA, NA, NA),
        ) + axis(1, at=seq(1,3),labels=colnames(counts), las=2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si eventualmente quieres las etiquetas con alguna inclinación:

```
x <- barplot(counts, 
        main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        xaxt="n")

text(cex=1, x=x, y=-1.25, colnames(counts), xpd=TRUE, srt=45, pos=2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]